# Touchpad randomly clicks on Dell Latitudes

Tags: touchpad, dell

A few times per week, my touchpad just starts randomly clicking. The mouse pointer is not moved, it's just clicking (sometimes with increasing intensity).

I know it is caused by the touchpad, because if I turn it off with the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, the clicking stops. Also, if I then *wait for 5-10 seconds* and turn the touchpad back on, the clicking stops. (If I just wait for minutes, without turning the touchpad off and on again, the clicking does not stop.)

I own two Dell Latitude laptops, an E6520 and an E6530 and it occurs on both of them, so it is probably not a hardware malfunction. I used 16.04-based Xubuntu and Mint Cinnamon installations, so the issue is unlikely to be specific to a certain windowing system.

On Windows, this error does not occur. I did not try any non-Ubuntu based distributions.

I do have the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package installed. Of course, I'm happy to provide more information on the install packages and drivers if needed.

Update #1: a year later, I moved to 18.04 and the problem still persists.

Update #2: I captured the log using the `xinput --test 18` command. Unfortunately, it is only a sequence of button press and release events:

```
button press   1 
button release 1 
button press   1 
button release 1 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how relevant it is but I found this:

[Touchpad on specific Latitude laptops is erratic or freezing when AC adapter or LAN cable is connected](https://www.dell.com/support/article/ca/en/cabsdt1/sln284958/touchpad-on-specific-latitude-laptops-is-erratic-or-freezing-when-ac-adapter-or-lan-cable-is-connected?lang=en)

I have a couple of Dell's and I've found that downloading Windows drivers and installing them can sometimes cure the ills in my Linux / Ubuntu too.

You can check out this Debian laptop review: [Installing Debian On Dell Latitude E6530 (wheezy)](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Dell/Latitude%20E6530%20%28wheezy%29)

> touch signal is erratic when multi-touch is used (i.e. 2-finger
>   scroll, 3-finger zoom, 3-finger right-click, etc.).
>
> Experience across the web shows many issues with Latitude TrackPad -
>   i.e. primarily touch/gesture related (see: Launchpad #1228471 and
>   Launchpad #606238 - would've used Debian Bug record but getting
>   Internal Server Error on search). Solution of adding Sid/unstable
>   repository for latest (1.7.3-1+b1 according to reportbug)
>   xserver-xorg-input-synaptics package, essentially results in a
>   dist-upgrade due to dependencies. Given closed nature of firmware,
>   unlikely to be resolved in package until hardware closer to obsolete,
>   or not at all.

Comment: Thanks for trying - installing a Win driver is something I'd never thought of, but will definitely give it a go. I'll also try to disable anything that's multitouch/gesture related. My `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is at version `1.9.0-1ubuntu1`

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround that worked for me was to disable tapping the touchpad to click.

To do so go to System Settings > Mouse & Touchpad > Untick "Tap to click".